# Update array object after custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a custom filter that I'm using to aggregate a $scope object that is being used in an ng-repeat block.
my code looks like this:

```
  $scope.myobj = isSelected ? $filter('customFilter')($scope.origObj) : $scope.origObj
```

As in the above code, `$scope.myobj` is what i use in the ng-repeat so if the `isselected` flag is true the original object is filtered and returned into `$scope.myobj` else we just return the original object as is.
However , any changes I make to any object in the filtered array do not get updated in the original array, understandably so as they are different objects.

How can I ensure that these changes reflect in the original array when the filter isn't active? 
I have a work around which is to just refresh the view after update(server request) but I'm wondering if there is a better way as I would like to only update the current row I'm editing and not do a full refresh.

Comment: can you make a minimal working example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Better way to do this is to create a custom filter which will accept a parameter and use it inside `ng-repeat`.

```
.filter('myFilter', function(){
return function(inputArr, isSelected){
    var outputArr = [];
    if(isSelected){
        outputArr = inputArr.filter(function(obj){return obj.active === true});
    }
    else{
        outputArr = inputArr;
    }
    return outputArr;
}
})
```

Working [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gilango/Lz9hgweL/). Hope this helps!